# Laravel create .po and .mo

Tags: laravel, gettext, poedit

I have a project in cloud 9 with laravel 5.5 and I have installed `"xinax/laravel-gettext": "4.x".`

When I write in the terminal laravel `php artisan gettext:update`. It creates po file for me.

But I would like to create my `.mo` file too without download and update the `po` file with poEdit, is it possible using command line directly?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this library do not generate `.mo` files. But You can contribute it :)

Answer (score -1):

To generate .mo files , you open the .po or .pot file with a program like PoEdit. Once you save the translation, it creates the .mo file for you in the same folder as the .po